# C++ DirectX 9 transforming a transformed vertex primitive

Tags: c++, directx, 2d, transformation, primitive

How would I go about transforming a primitive created with vertices that have an XYZRWH flag? From what I've read vertices with an XYZRWH ignore transformation. For instance, I have a camera that works for D3DSprites etc, but not for these primitives. Knowing I will be needing quite some primitives for a game I want to create, what's the best way to do it? Making an untransformed primitive looking like a transformed one?

Comment: `D3DFVF_XYZRHW` is usually used for vertices that should remain in the same place, such as GUI elements or HUD. If you want to transform them, then don't use that flag.

Comment: So I would have to use untransformed vertices?